# How can I preprocess my Mapdataset to fit my model input?

Tags: tensorflow, tfrecord

I use a MapDataset compose of label in text and a vector of float in string.
Here is the way I read the content of my tfrecord:

```
def extract_data(tfrecord_ds):
    feature_description = {
        'classes_text': tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string),
        'data': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
    }

def _parse_data_function(example_proto):
    return tf.compat.v1.parse_single_example(example_proto, feature_description)
parsed_dataset = tfrecord_ds.map(_parse_data_function)

dataset = parsed_dataset.cache().shuffle(1000).batch(32).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
return dataset
```

I want to convert the **label_text** to int according to label.txt file and the **data** string to vector of float.

I want to use this data to train a custom model like this:

```
my_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1024), dtype=tf.float32,
                              name='input_embedding'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes)
    ], name='audio_detector')
```

How can I process my MapDataset from (string,string) to (int, float_array) to be able to train my model?

Edit:

Here is the way I encode my data:

```
 features = {}
                                features['classes_text'] = tf.train.Feature(
                                    bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[audio_data_generator.label.encode()]))
                                bytes = embedding.numpy().tobytes()
                                features['data'] = tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[bytes]))
                                tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=features))
                                writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())
```

Comment: How is the _data_ string encoded? Is it a comma separated string?

Comment: @Dimosthenis I modify my first message to answer your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier to encode the embedding using `tf.train.FloatList`.

When writing to tfrecords use:

```
features = {
  'classes_text': tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[label.encode()])),
  'data': tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=embedding))
}
tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=features))
writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())
```

And when reading give the embedding size to `tf.io.FixedLenFeature`, for example:

```
embedding_size = 10
feature_description = {
  'classes_text': tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string),
  'data': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([embedding_size], tf.float32)
}
```

To convert **label_text** to int you can use `tf.lookup.StaticVocabularyTable`.

```
# Assuming lable.txt contains a single label per line.
with open('label.txt', 'r') as fin:
  categories = [line.strip() for line in fin.readlines()]
init = tf.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(
    keys=tf.constant(categories),
    values=tf.constant(list(range(len(categories))), dtype=tf.int64))
label_table = tf.lookup.StaticVocabularyTable(
   init,
   num_oov_buckets=1)

feature_description = {
  'classes_text': tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string),
  'data': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([embedding_size], tf.float32)
}

def _parse_data_function(example_proto):
  example = tf.compat.v1.parse_single_example(example_proto, feature_description)
  # Apply the label lookup.
  example['classes_text'] = label_table.lookup(example['classes_text'])
  return example

parsed_dataset = tfrecord_ds.map(_parse_data_function)

dataset = parsed_dataset.cache().shuffle(1000).batch(32).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

### Edit

If you wish to keep the way you save data you can use `np.frombuffer` to convert the numpy vectors to from binary stings. You will have to wrap this code in a tf.function and tf.py_function though.

```
def decode_embedding(embedding_bytes):
  return np.frombuffer(embedding_bytes.numpy())
@tf.function()
def tf_decode_embedding(embedding_bytes):
  return tf.py_function(decode_embedding, inp=[embedding_bytes], Tout=tf.float32)

feature_description = {
        'classes_text': tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string),
        'data': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
    }

def _parse_data_function(example_proto):
    example = tf.compat.v1.parse_single_example(example_proto, feature_description)
    example['classes_text'] = label_table.lookup(example['classes_text'])
    example['data'] = tf_decode_embedding(example['data'])
    return example

parsed_dataset = tfrecord_ds.map(_parse_data_function)

dataset = parsed_dataset.cache().shuffle(1000).batch(32).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

Comment: I dont want to use float list because it obliged me to specify the size of my data. I my case my data size can  be different from tf record. Can I modify my embedding feature like you did with label?

Comment: If the embedding size does not have a fixed size you can either fill in zeros (and have a maximum size parameter) or use `tf.io.VarLenFeature`.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Another option is to use `tf.io.serialize_tensor(embedding).numpy()` when saving and `tf.io.parse_tensor(example['data'], tf.float32)` when parsing, without the need to use tf.py_funcion.